# How to disable internet but remain connected to LAN network?

Tags: firewall, local-area-network, internet

I have a windows computer that I want to isolate from the internet. I need this computer to remain in contact with other devices on the network and be able to VNC into it.

I saw some solutions saying to change the default gateway / DNS but this doesn't actually isolate the PC from the internet.

I was thinking there could be a way to do this with windows firewall but I'm not an expert. Tried searching online and couldn't find an easy answer!

Thanks!

Comment: Just delete default gateway.

Comment: This has been already answered here:
https://superuser.com/questions/586517/disable-internet-access-but-leave-lan-working

Answer (score 1):

Change its default gateway to one that does not route to the Internet.

Usually this would be implemented with a VLAN. Take care to not let its router discover paths to your Internet gateway.